# How to count page views made by users in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple rails app where users can login and post updates what i want to do is add a count in each post so if someone visit a post it will get updated suppose if 100 users visited a particular post it should show the count to hundred.

I had seen impressionist but i was thinking to do this without using a gem.

i thought of creating another **Modal** `PostView`

```
class PageView
    belongs_to :page
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Have a look at the `impressionist` gem: https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist

Answer (score 3):

Basically you can add additional field to post, like `visit_counter`:

```
class Post
  def increase_visit
    visit_counter+=1
    save!
  end
end
```

Then in `posts_controller#show`, you can do some increment:

```
class PostsController
  def show
  ............
  @post.increase_visit
  end
end
```

That means, every time you render `posts#show` view someone actually visited particular post so you should increment number of visits.

In case you need more flexible and advance approach ( to count visits per user, or per days etc ) you can define separate model `VisitCounter` which would be associated with your `Post` model.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can add a views field in the model and increment it on each page view

```
def change
  add_column :page_views, :count, :integer, default: 0
end
```

and

```
# app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
def increment
  @pageview = PageView.where(user_id: current_user, page_id: params[:id]).first_or_create
  @pageview.increment!(:count)
end
```

And just add a route in pages controller

```
# routes.rb
resources :pages do 
  post :increment 
end
```

Comment: You should use the bang `!` version of `increment` method, or record don't be saved. https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!

Answer (score 2):

Since it wasn't mentioned yet, you should also checkout https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist which makes view tracking very easy and flexible.

This is the data which is saved with each view and could get handy later:

```
t.string   "impressionable_type"  # model type: Widget
t.integer  "impressionable_id"    # model instance ID: @widget.id
t.integer  "user_id"              # automatically logs @current_user.id
t.string   "controller_name"      # logs the controller name
t.string   "action_name"          # logs the action_name
t.string   "view_name"            # TODO: log individual views (as well as partials and nested partials)
t.string   "request_hash"         # unique ID per request, in case you want to log multiple impressions and group them
t.string   "session_hash"         # logs the rails session
t.string   "ip_address"           # request.remote_ip
t.text     "params"               # request.params, except action name, controller name and resource id
t.string   "referrer"             # request.referer
t.string   "message"              # custom message you can add
```

So for example you could query something like: "Give me all views for a specific user grouped by Model and Sessions." and stuff like this.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for a large project (thousands/millions of users) is
punching bag gem , go through the doc for integration : [punching_bag](https://github.com/biola/punching_bag)

The major problem arises when with each request a new record is created which puts huge load on database. Gem Impressionist fails here. Punching bag too creates records but it has a rake task which comes to rescue :

Schedule a cron job to this rake task once a month/week to decrease (groups the records) the number of records without affecting the count of page views which can be found by simply - @post.hits .
Here is the rake task :
rake punching_bag:combine[by_hour_after,by_day_after,by_month_after,by_year_after]

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Deepak, you can add a views field in the model,

```
def change
  add_column :page_views, :count, :integer, default: 0
end
```

Then, in your `controller` in `show` action,

```
def show
  #your show logic
  if (user = current_user).present?
    current_user.page_views.where(page_id: @page.id).first_or_initialize.increment!(:count)
  end
end
```

This makes sense because whenever the page is visited, counter should be incremented by 1..and your post request is saved..

Answer (score 0):

Let's think we have a blog with articles. In index page article name ,text and theme of the article will be printed.so we have to introduce a new column to index page of having no of views of an each article.

Do following  changes.

**app/view/articles/index.html.erb**

1. add to the table .

   ```
   <th>view</th>
   ```
2. add to the data abstract part start with

   ```
   <%@articles.each_with_index do |article, index| %>  .

   <td><%= article.view %></td>
   ```

**add a new column to articles database as view**

1. If you are using mysql you can manually add the column as view, make default value as 0.
2. or run the code

   ```
   rails generate migration add_view_to_article view:int
   ```

**app/controller/articles.controller.rb**

```
def show
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
abc = @article.view += 1
@article.update_attribute "view", abc
end
```